# Difference between style="display: block" and style="display: "

Tags: html, css

I understand `style="display: none"` hides an HTML element, and `style="display: block"` displays a block-level HTML element.

I saw some historic code using `style="display: "`, which also displays the element.

What's the difference between `style="display: block"` and `style="display: "`?

Comment: `style="display: "` is simply invalid and changes nothing.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `style="display: "` does nothing, since there isn't a value defined and therefor invalid.

So the element will be displayed (by default).

Please note that `display` also accepts other values that also will display the elements, but will render them differently. More info about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 1):

`style="display: "` is invalid. The attempt to set the property will be ignored. The value of `display` will be taken from the cascade instead.

That might mean it will take the browser default value for `display` for the element type, or it might take the value from a ruleset in the stylesheet.

You can get the same effect with `style=""` without being invalid.